# css for displaying image and text in same line

Tags: html, css

I want to display the text and image in same line but image display  slight above from text.[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/1z9b9m9p/3/)

```css
 html img.del {
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;
   cursor: pointer;
   margin-right: 74%
 }
 .astext {
   text-align: left;
   margin-left: 10%;
 }
```

```html
 <h4><span><a class="astext" href="'.$next.'" title="'.$next.'" target="_blank" download><p style="margin-left:1cm;">'.$next1.'</a></span>
       <img src="image/delete1.png" class="del" alt="delete" style="width:10px;height:10px" title="Remove" onclick="myFunction('.$fet['f_id'].');"></h4>
```

Comment: You cannot have `paragraph`s inside h4 elements. Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: add 'margin-top:x;' to img.del. where x is number.

Comment: check my updated fiddle

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you got some open tags in your code:

second: i updated your fiddle to work correctly:

```
 img.del {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 74%;
    position: relative;
    }
.astext {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

this is how it should be displayed right?

`float: right` and `display: inline-block` do not work together since they **sort of** the same thing. 
see this reference: http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block

and here is your fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/1z9b9m9p/4/